# Bulkinsert unable to access destination table [].[table]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bulkinsert

**Edit: Fixed.
However, i do kinda feel like an idiot. The table i was inserting to did not have a primary key specified. However given the error message i was given, this was not something i thought of.**

We currently have a table in a schema. Lets call that Stock. In that schema there is a table called Data. So [Stock].[Data].
When using BulkInsert from EntityFramework.Extensions however, we get the following error message: Cannot access destination table '[].[Data].

As you can see, the Schema is missing. However i cannot find any way to add it. The model is autogenerated from the database using EntityFramework.
The user has access to the table

```
using(StockEntities context = new StockEntities())
{
    var entities = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<Data>>(listData).ToArray();
    context.BulkInsert(entities);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In regards to the question below, the model has been set up in the following way. I have already tried changing the database scheme name (which was set to dbo) and the namespace from stock to stockmodel. However, it still wont work.

[image: StockModel]

Comment: i believe you can re-generate from the db specifying a schema - try doing a google around that

Comment: I have updated the question, is that what you meant?

Comment: I would check to see if the table was generated in the database.  Use SQL Server Management Studio (comes with SQL Server) and verify using the SSMS explorer that the table was generated in the database and the columns are properly defined.

Comment: The table exists in the database (created in myself). However, it has been created first using a select into statement instead of a normal create table method due to the number of fields.

Comment: I'm the owner of Entity Framework Extensions, I recommend you to send your `EDMX` file and the create table script to our support team directly: info@zzzprojects.com, otherwise, please check using SQL Profiler what the script that is executed is, you might miss some other schema name change.